# I can fetch remote config parameters but I don't see the analysis data in iOS project

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics, firebase-remote-config

I have added firebase to my other project and it worked without any problem and i could see my analysis , but recently non of my new projects show analysis and the thing is that i can fetch remote config parameters but i can't see the analysis and daily users anymore.

Is there anything i'm missing ?

I have added firebase through pod.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok , It looks like that Xcode doesn't add the -ObjC in linker flags.

I Solve this problem by going to Target -> Build Settings -> Other Linker Flags , and then adding -ObjC at the end of the file.

Also check the GoogleService-Info.plist file and turn on IS_ANALYTICS_ENABLED to true (1).